# How to delete MapImage from Ammap.js

Tags: amcharts, ammap

I have been using Ammap Library and created Map.
https://www.amcharts.com/demos/custom-html-elements-map-markers/

I want to delete Map images object by using method(), Details are in below link.
Could any one let me know how to use this method()

https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptmaps/MapImage#deleteObject
Method Name:"deleteObject()"

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`deleteObject` is a member method of the image/object itself, so you just call it from the object you want to delete, e.g.

`image.deleteObject();`

If your map is using custom HTML elements like in the demo, you also need to remove the div generated in your `createCustomMarker` method by calling `removeChild` in the DOM. You need to be able to access that div somehow, so I recommend modifying it to set the div's `id` to something you can look up later like the image's id:

```
// this function creates and returns a new marker element
function createCustomMarker(image) {
  // create holder
  var holder = document.createElement("div");
  holder.className = "map-marker";
  holder.title = image.title;
  holder.id = image.id; //added to make div lookup easier
  // ...
}
```

This modification assumes you set an id in your images, which is also recommended since you can use the `getObjectById` method to get the image object and call its `deleteObject` method.

Here's a sample function that deletes both the image and custom marker when an image ID is provided:

```
function deleteImage(imageId) {
  var image = map.getObjectById(imageId);
  var imageDiv;
  if (image) {
    image.deleteObject(); //delete the ammap image object
    imageDiv = document.getElementById(imageId); //get the custom marker div
    imageDiv.parentNode.removeChild(imageDiv); //remove it from the DOM
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/2c970fc18b919bc9819dbfc8b3d23967?editors=0010) - Click on the buttons to delete the corresponding marker.

Comment: Thank you very much that is very helpful